# Why wasn’t the bounty awarded to this accepted, upvoted answer?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

I offered a bounty for my question … then I accepted the answer; but the bounty was not awarded to the accepted answer, which also had a score >= 2.

**Question link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168232/set-attach-invisible-unseen-attribute-value-into-html-element-through-vanilla-js)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bounty ended 10 hours ago. There should still be an option to award it for you, right? If so, you can click the answer and award the bounty. Otherwise, if you don't award it, it'll go to that accepted answer automatically once the grace period expires (24h after bounty ends)

Comment: grace period also expires.

Comment: @CertainPerformancei actually i did not get you...

Comment: @noor The grace period shouldn't have ended, right?

Comment: i put the link .. please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168232/set-attach-invisible-unseen-attribute-value-into-html-element-through-vanilla-js)

Comment: Have a read of the "How is a bounty awarded?" section in [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: @HansPassant actually if you go through the revisions, the bounty wants to reward an existing answer.

Comment: *"Only answers that are posted after the bounty got started are eligible"* Isn't that for automatic awards, not when the person that created the bounty chose to award it, @HansPassant ?

Comment: i accept it on grace period

Comment: I put reward an existing answer....

Comment: @noor Correct me if Im wrong, but there should be a +50 below the accepted answer. Just click that and it will award the bounty.

Comment: where i will click ?

Comment: Below the accepted answer mark.

Comment: @yivi The bounty was supposed to reward an _existing_ answer. It says that in the post revisions.

Comment: i accept the answer on grace perigod..

Comment: But you need to award the bounty, @noor, not accept the answer...

Comment: @10Rep I guess they should have awarded it, then. It doesn’t auto award to existing answers.

Comment: I think what was tripping us up here is that the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64168232/timeline) "Bounty ended" shows not when the bounty *proper* ends (7 days later), but when the grace period ends (8 days later). The grace period for this question ended a few hours ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bounty is only automatically awarded to *new* answers. No answer was posted after you started the bounty.

You can verify this on the post  [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64168232/timeline).

If you wanted to reward an existing answer, you should have awarded it manually.

The “bounty reason” does not affect auto-award rules.

Comment: how i will reward manually ?

Comment: There is a button to do so while the bounty is active. Not anymore.